# What is a WebKitLoadEvent and how can I get it in order to use a "load-change" signal Callback

Tags: c, linux, webkit, gtk3

I have read about the load-change signal which can be emitted when a load operation in web_view changes.(https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html#WebKitWebView-load-changed)
And I need to use this but I don't understand how I can get the WebKitLoadEvent load_event to acctualy use this function. I didn't see any other function which returns a WebKitLoadEvent. How do I use this function?

```
static void web_view_load_changed (WebKitWebView   *web_view,WebKitLoadEvent  load_event, gpointer data)
{
  struct widget *w = (struct widget *)data;
  const gchar *redirected_uri;
  const gchar *uri;
  GTimer *timer = g_timer_new ();

    switch (load_event) {
    case WEBKIT_LOAD_STARTED:
        break;
    case WEBKIT_LOAD_REDIRECTED:
        break;
    case WEBKIT_LOAD_COMMITTED:
        break;
    case WEBKIT_LOAD_FINISHED:                            
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this signal is beeing emitted from web_view. So in order to use this you only need to connect this function with the web_view at the place where your web_view is created.

This should look like this:

```
web_view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
g_signal_connect(web_view, "load-change", G_CALLBAK(web_view_load_changed), (gpointer) data);
```